# Aligning textboxes via HTML

Tags: html

Here is my code:

```
Classroom name:                <input type="text" name="txtClassroomName" size="20"><br>
School name:                   <input type="text" name="txtSchoolName" size="20"><br>
School contact email address:  <input type="text" name="txtSchoolEmail" size="20"><br>
School address:                <input type="text" name="txtSchoolAddress" size="20"><br>
School telephone number:       <input type="text" name="txtTelephoneNumber" size="20"><br>
```

As you can probably guess, this code displays some text and then has some textboxes after this text.

My question is this: I am wanting to align all the texboxes so that they are aligned. I have added spaces after the text, yet the textboxes just appear straight after the text, ignoring the spaces that I entered. What is the best, most effective way to do this? Maybe a table?

thanks

Comment: A table is the *easiest* way.  Hopefully the table layout police will come by and show you how to do it with divs.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Well, how hard can it be? http://jsfiddle.net/24nnv/2/

Answer (score 12):

Normally you'd use css to do this for you. in your css file add:

```
label{
display:inline-block;
width:200px;
margin-right:30px;
text-align:right;
}

input{

}

fieldset{
border:none;
width:500px;
margin:0px auto;
}
```

Then in the html you would set the labels up next to the textboxes:

```
<fieldset>
<label for="txtClassroomName">Classroom name:</label><input type="text" name="txtClassroomName" size="20">
<label for="txtSchoolName">School name:</label><input type="text" name="txtSchoolName" size="20">
<label for="txtSchoolEmail">School contact email address:</label><input type="text" name="txtSchoolEmail" size="20">
<label for="txtSchoolEmail">School address:</label><input type="text" name="txtSchoolAddress" size="20">
<label for="txtSchoolEmail">School telephone number:</label><input type="text" name="txtTelephoneNumber" size="20">
</fieldset>
```

in the css file, the margin-right:30px; line tells it how far apart to put the label and textbox

setting the fieldset width essentially creates a box round it all and you can set it's width if you need to make any labels bigger.

Hope that helps.

Martyn

Comment: Thanks Martyn. That works well. A question: What is the best way to align the labels and the textboxes in the center, while still having the 30px margins?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean in the center of the page, you can alter the css for the fieldset so it is central. Edited my answer to include margin:0px auto; in the fieldset css

Answer (score 5):

```
<table>
<tr><td><label for="txtClassroomName">Classroom name:</label>                
  <td><input type="text" name="txtClassroomName" id="txtClassroomName" size="20">
<tr><td><label for="txtSchoolName">School name:</label>
  <input type="text" name="txtSchoolName" id="txtSchoolName" size="20"><br>

...
</table>
```

A table is the only way to make the columns aligned so that the first column occupies just the width it needs (the width of the longest label). Any other approach forces you to make a guess on the width, and the results will inevitably vary, and the code will not be robust (the width needs to be adjusted whenever the length of the longest label changes).

Answer (score 2):

In HTML, continuous SPACEs are taken as a single space only. So you need HTML Special Character for the SPACE, that is `&nbsp;`

`Classroom name:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="text" name="txtClassroomName" size="20"><br>`

**But, this is the dirty way.** This is not the standard way to do so. Also, this doesn't sure that the textboxes will align same until you use some mono-space fonts.

So, you should consider either `<TABLE>` tag or CSS.

Comment: Vishnu: Can you please give me an example of how to add textboxes within a table. Thanks.

Comment: @MrLister, what's wrong with using a table where it's not needed?  Isn't it a valid way to accomplish the goal?  Did you also down vote the other table answer?

Comment: +1 to counter the downvote from Mr. Lister. The table is the real solution. Guessing how long the text will be is a silly, hacky method. A table will ensure the first column is only as long as it is needed (length of longest label).

Answer (score 0):

You can also make all the textboxes to appear one below the other in  the  center of your screen. It will look uniform.